# Generalized Doob martingale property?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable and $\mathcal H$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

The Doob martingale property says $E(X \mid E(X \mid \mathcal{H}))=E(X \mid \mathcal{H})$ (proved by using the tower property).

Now suppose that we have two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal H_1$, $\mathcal H_2$.

Can we say something about

$$E(X \mid E(X \mid \mathcal{H_1}), E(X \mid \mathcal{H_2}))$$

My intuition: the Doob martingale property says that the best approximation of $X$ knowing the approximation $E(X \mid \mathcal{H})$ is $E(X \mid \mathcal{H})$. That would mean that $E(X \mid E(X \mid \mathcal{H_1}), E(X \mid \mathcal{H_2})) = E(X \mid \mathcal{H_2})$ if $\mathcal H_1 \subseteq \mathcal H_2$ since $E(X \mid \mathcal{H_2})$ contains more information about $X$. What do you think?

Comment: as far as I know you cannot prove that $E(X | E(X | \mathcal{H}))=E(X|\mathcal{H})$ just using the power property, because $\sigma (E(X|\mathcal{H}))\subset \mathcal{H}$

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the question?  Are you asking whether it is true that if $\mathcal H_1 \subseteq \mathcal H_2$ then $E[X \mid E[X \mid \mathcal{H_1}], E[X \mid \mathcal{H_2}]) = E[X \mid \mathcal{H_2}]$?  That is true and follows pretty directly from the tower property.

Comment: @Masacroso: Yes, I think you can.  Let's let $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(E[X \mid \mathcal{H}]) \subseteq \mathcal{H}$.  Then $E[X \mid \mathcal{G}] = E[E[X \mid \mathcal{H}] \mid \mathcal{G}]$ by tower, but this equals $E[X \mid \mathcal{H}]$ because $E[X \mid \mathcal{H}]$ is already $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.  And the claim at the end of the question has exactly the same proof, letting instead $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(E[X \mid \mathcal{H}_1], E[X \mid \mathcal{H}_2]) \subseteq \mathcal{H}_2$.

Comment: @Nate ah! you are right. I didnt see that $E[X|\mathcal{H}]$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable!

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, I just needed to see that $\sigma\left(E\left[X \mid \mathcal{H}_{1}\right], E\left[X \mid \mathcal{H}_{2}\right]\right) \subseteq \mathcal{H}_{2}$!

Comment: @W.Volante: Yeah, it look me a while to realize as well.  I thought about several possible counterexamples, then finally decided to just try to prove the statement directly from the definition of conditional expectation, and then it all became immediately clear.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually, an alternative way would simply be: $H_1 \subseteq H_2$ implies that $\sigma (E[X| H_1]) \subseteq \sigma (E[X|H_2])$ ? Is this true ?

Comment: @W.Volante: That is not true, same counterexample as [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374299/on-conditional-expectations-and-sigma-algebras?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @NateEldredge Correct! Thank you. Here is another one that is kinda related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376124/on-conditional-independence-under-transformation